# Boolean seemingly changing itself (XNA)

Tags: c#, xna, boolean

I am currently working on a save system in my XNA game that fires off an event when it's finished saving.

My game has multiple screens which are managed by a screen manager, each screen has its own Update and Draw methods.

In the constructor, my _newSave boolean is flagged as true, this boolean starts off the game save process (which is managed by helper), and once it starts the process, it is flagged to false to prevent constant looping (since i only want to save once per save screen).

When helper is finished saving, it fires off the event, back inside the SaveScreen class, which sets _newSave back to true, and tells the ScreenManager to change screens.

Playing the game everything seems to work correctly, until the second time saving, when this save is attempted the game freezes. It is worth noting that this bool is private and only used in this method the 4 times shown (found usage by visual studio to confirm)

```
class SaveScreen : LoadingScreen
{
    private bool _newSave;
    private Player _player;

    public SaveScreen(EventHandler screenEvent, ContentManager Content, GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice, Player player)
        : base(screenEvent, Content, GraphicsDevice)
    {
        screenTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("saving");
        _newSave = true;
        this._player = player;
        helper.FinishedSaving = new EventHandler(FinishedSaving);
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (_newSave)
        {
            helper.RequestSave(_player);
            _newSave = false;
        }

        helper.UpdateSaving();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    private void FinishedSaving(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        _newSave = true;
        screenEvent.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

With a breakpoint inside the FinishedSaving event, i confirmed that the bool is changing to true, which is correct, however, a following breakpoint on the next save cycle on the if statement, shows that bool is false.

I am so completely confused by this, as the only _newSave = false statement is inside the if statement that needs to be true to access, the breakpoint inside the event shows that it is true, yet on the first "new" loop of the update code, it is false.

I am really pulling my hair out with this and cannot understand what's happening.

Any help is hugely appreciated, and i'm sorry if it's something silly, i'm a relatively new programmer :)

Thank You! <3

EDIT: Pastebin of entire Helper.cs class: http://pastebin.com/uJ0g6e00

Loading Screen Class: pastebin.com/8W8HxBnq

Screen Class: pastebin.com/qr29gzuq

Comment: Try to set a variable breakpoint that triggers whenever a variable is modified; not too sure if it's available in C# though; are you using multiple threads, maybe an Async operation?

Comment: When (and how often) does Update get called? What does helper.RequestSave and helper.UpdateSaving do? Do they cause FinshedSaving to fire?

Comment: I guarantee you the problem is within `RequestSave` because it calls `LoadingScreen` everytime it does it sets `_newsave` to false.  You should learn the proper way to name variables btw.

Comment: I am not using multiple threads, and i wouldn't know how to use an async operation (only used them during saving before with StorageContainer and StorageDevice checks), here are Request save simply sets a state inside helper, which will allow UpdateSaving to perform what it needs to in order to save i.e. creating StorageDevice and StorageContainer, then saving, once the save is fully completed, FinishedSaving is fired. Here is a pastebin of the entire helper class! http://pastebin.com/uJ0g6e00 (sorry if it's not very well written :P)

Comment: Ramhound FinishedSaving is only called when UpdateSaving reaches the end of the cycle shown in the Helper.cs, As for my variable naming, i am simply using what i have been taught at univiersity and what resharper suggests

Comment: And i'm not sure what you mean by it calls LoadingScreen, SaveScreen is inherited from LoadingScreen, and this is what is inside it - http://pastebin.com/8W8HxBnq, LoadingScreen inherits simply from Screen, which contains only this - http://pastebin.com/qr29gzuq

Comment: @StephenFoster: You have FinishedSaving being invoked in two places. In UpdateSaving and in RequestSave. It's really hard to follow the logic of what you are trying to do however.

Comment: @StephenFoster: and O/T, Ramhound can speak for themselves on what their problem with your variable names is, but having something called "SaveScreen" inherit from something called "LoadingScreen" is a little perverse.

Comment: I invoke FinishedSaving inside UpdateSaving under the else statement, meaning that i do not want to save (since the current score is not greater than the loaded score), Would you please suggest better names because i don't understand the issue :/ like i said i'm pretty new to programming

Comment: To clarify further, what happens inside the other classes really does not change the fact that a private boolean is being changed, and the ONLY possible statement that can change it to false is inside a if conditional that has a break point on it so i can track AS SOON as the value is changed, it is never changed by this conditional, yet the value changes anyway, even after break point flagged true.

Comment: I have used Resharper before and using `_player` as a player name is not suggested by it.  If anything that should be a property marked private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, apologies to everyone for wasting their time, and thank you for trying to help, turns out that simply switching the _newSave; = false and helper.RequestSave(_player); statements around fixed the issue, I thought that the problem was isolated into this class alone due it being the only place where the changes happened, in fact the issue was that i invoked the delegate inside the RequestSave method when the player score was not greater than the high score, this caused the code to then return to the if block and since the "_newSave = false;" statement was directly after the method call, it was reverting the statement back to false!

So silly of me but sometimes it's really hard to see the simple problems :P Thank you again!

<3

Comment: I find it funny the problem was within `RequestSave` considering it was the only method you didn't post.

Comment: I'm really elated that you find that funny, but the method is inside the helper class which i DID post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple threads? If so, I wonder whether it's a race condition.

For example:

`Update` is called

Let's suppose that `_newSave` is true

`RequestSave` is called

Before `RequestSave` returns, `Update` is called again, but `_newSave` is still true...

Comment: I am not using multiple threads unless they are used by default with EventHandler?